# How to create a window with alpha-channel transparency, using wxPython?

Tags: python, image, wxpython, transparency, alpha

Hey there, first time asking.

I have been trying to use wxPython to create an overlay windows to be displayed over other programs, however I can't seem to figure out how to make an image appear with an alpha-channel transparency over my desktop.

In the future I will be planning to have buttons on top of the image also.

Something like [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/), but with an image that has an alpha so that you can see the window behind it.

Comment: Is the program supposed to be platform-independent? Do you plan to use the real alpha-channel, as opposed to one-bit transparency? (I'm not sure if the former is possible on Windows, that is.)

Comment: @Helgi: on the contrary, it's on Windows that the full alpha channel is available, and on Linux that it's not (the composition manager supports the alpha channel just fine, but wxWidgets doesn't recognise it).

Comment: The window doesn't require an alpha channel because that can be done with the image I think, just the window background needs to be transparent to see through the parts of the image that are transparent.

Answer (score 0):

To make a wxPython application transparent, you need to make the Frame itself transparent. Which you found out in that tutorial I wrote a while back. Images are a little different. There are examples in the demo and in the wxPython mailing list archives though. See also [wxPython - drawing on transparent/alpha background (for custom widgets/panels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159581/wxpython-drawing-on-transparent-alpha-background-for-custom-widgets-panels)  and http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages

Comment: I can't seem to find how to make the frame transparent without making the image transparent as. Would I use the same alpha drawing for the image's in the demo for the frame? If so how do I apply it to the window and not just the image?

Comment: I was afraid of that. I would cross-post to the wxPython mailing list. I'll try to get someone from there to come here too.